# File Checksums in Python

Tags: python, django, file, checksum

I am creating an application related to files. And I was looking for ways to compute checksums for files. I want to know what's the best hashing method to calculate checksums of files md5 or SHA-1 or something else based on this criterias

- The checksum should be unique. I know its theoretical but still I want the probablity of collisions to be very very small.
- Can compare two files to be equal if there checksums are equal or not.
- Speed(not very important, but still)

Please feel free to as elaborative as possible.

Comment: md5 tends to work great for checksums ... same with SHA-1 ... both have very small probability of collisions although I think SHA-1 has slightly smaller collision probability  since it uses more bits

Comment: And any comparison as to which one of them is faster?? And will I be sure that if two files have same checksum than they are equal?

Comment: you can run timeit against them ... and no its not 100% guaranteed ... just very unlikely to have collisions ...

Comment: Ok. I understand about the collision thing. So what should I do to check the uniqueness of a file.

Comment: you could use both checksums (one md5 and one sha1)  the chance that both match and the files differ is infinitesimally small (still not 100% impossible but very very very unlikely) ... typically (read: in every instance I have ever encountered) an MD5 OR an SHA1 match is sufficient to assume uniqueness

Comment: Are you worried about someone deliberately trying to generate collisions (e.g., so they can distribute a tampered file and fool your checks)? Or just accidental collisions?

Comment: Thanks. And if you can please post an answer stating all this is better manner and than I can approve it.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: There's really not that much benefit in checking both MD5 and SHA1. You're effectively doing twice the work for much less than 1% extra benefit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your use case.

If you're only worried about accidental collisions, both MD5 and SHA-1 are fine, and MD5 is generally faster. In fact, MD4 is also sufficient for most use cases, and usually even faster… but it isn't as widely-implemented. (In particular, it isn't in `hashlib.algorithms_guaranteed`… although it should be in `hashlib_algorithms_available` on most stock Mac, Windows, and Linux builds.)

On the other hand, if you're worried about intentional attacks—i.e., someone intentionally crafting a bogus file that matches your hash—you have to consider the value of what you're protecting. MD4 is almost definitely not sufficient, MD5 is probably not sufficient, but SHA-1 is borderline. At present, Keccak (which will soon by SHA-3) is believed to be the best bet, but you'll want to stay on top of this, because things change every year.

The Wikipedia page on [Cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) has a table that's usually updated pretty frequently. To understand the table:

To generate a collision against an MD4 requires only 3 rounds, while MD5 requires about 2 million, and SHA-1 requires 15 trillion. That's enough that it would cost a few million dollars (at today's prices) to generate a collision. That may or may not be good enough for you, but it's not good enough for NIST.

---

Also, remember that "generally faster" isn't nearly as important as "tested faster on my data and platform". With that in mind, in 64-bit Python 3.3.0 on my Mac, I created a 1MB random `bytes` object, then did this:

```
In [173]: md4 = hashlib.new('md4')
In [174]: md5 = hashlib.new('md5')
In [175]: sha1 = hashlib.new('sha1')
In [180]: %timeit md4.update(data)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 ms per loop
In [181]: %timeit md5.update(data)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop
In [182]: %timeit sha1.update(data)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.94 ms per loop
```

As you can see, `md4` is significantly faster than the others.

Tests using `hashlib.md5()` instead of `hashlib.new('md5')`, and using `bytes` with less entropy (runs of 1-8 `string.ascii_letters` separated by spaces) didn't show any significant differences.

And, for the hash algorithms that came with my installation, as tested below, nothing beat md4.

```
for x in hashlib.algorithms_available:
    h = hashlib.new(x)
    print(x, timeit.timeit(lambda: h.update(data), number=100))
```

---

If speed is really important, there's a nice trick you can use to improve on this: Use a bad, but very fast, hash function, like `zlib.adler32`, and only apply it to the first 256KB of each file. (For some file types, the last 256KB, or the 256KB nearest the middle without going over, etc. might be better than the first.) Then, if you find a collision, generate MD4/SHA-1/Keccak/whatever hashes on the whole file for each file.

---

Finally, since someone asked in a comment how to hash a file without reading the whole thing into memory:

```
def hash_file(path, algorithm='md5', bufsize=8192):
    h = hashlib.new(algorithm)
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        block = f.read(bufsize)
        if not block:
            break
        h.update(block)
    return h.digest()
```

If squeezing out every bit of performance is important, you'll want to experiment with different values for `bufsize` on your platform (powers of two from 4KB to 8MB). You also might want to experiment with using raw file handles (`os.open` and `os.read`), which may sometimes be faster on some platforms.

Comment: No speed is not that important but just a consideration. I have decided to use SHA-1 as I thought it would be a fine blend for speed and security. Do you think its a good choice?

Comment: I approved your answer as I found it to be the explanatory one. Thanks

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra: Well, I don't have the information to be sure it's the right tradeoff for your use case or not… but it's a good choice pretty often, which is why it's so common, so I certainly wouldn't be surprised if it was a good choice for you.

Comment: I was hoping if you can help me in another question also...please have a look and see if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816815/authentication-in-android

Comment: The "how to hash a file without reading the whole thing into memory" edit seems to be missing a while loop that continues to read until the file is fully consumed.

Answer (score 2):

The collision possibilities with hash size of sufficient bits are , [theoretically](http://web.archive.org/web/20110725085124/http://bitcache.org/faq/hash-collision-probabilities), quite small:

> Assuming random hash values with a uniform distribution, a collection
>   of n different data blocks and a hash function that generates b bits,
>   the probability p that there will be one or more collisions is bounded
>   by the number of pairs of blocks multiplied by the probability that a
>   given pair will collide, i.e

[image]

And, so far, SHA-1 collisions with 160 bits have been unobserved. Assuming one exabyte (10^18) of data, in 8KB blocks, the theoretical chance of a collision is 10^-20 -- a very very small chance.

A useful shortcut is to eliminate files known to be different from each other through short-circuiting.

For example, in outline:

1. Read the first X blocks of all files of interest;
2. Sort the one that have the same hash for the first X blocks as potentially the same file data;
3. For each file with the first X blocks that are unique, you can assume the entire file is unique vs all other tested files -- you do not need to read the rest of that file;
4. With the remaining files, read more blocks until you prove the signatures are the same or different.

With X blocks of sufficient size, 95%+ of the files will be correctly discriminated into unique files in the first pass. This is much faster than blindly reading the entire file and calculating the full hash for each and every file.

Answer (score 1):

md5 tends to work great for checksums ... same with SHA-1 ... both have very small probability of collisions although I think SHA-1 has slightly smaller collision probability since it uses more bits

if you are really worried about it, you could use both checksums (one md5 and one sha1) the chance that both match and the files differ is infinitesimally small (still not 100% impossible but very very very unlikely) ... (this seems like bad form and by far the slowest solution)

typically (read: in every instance I have ever encountered) an MD5 OR an SHA1 match is sufficient to **assume** uniqueness

there is no way to 100% guarantee uniqueness short of byte by byte comparisson

Comment: MD5 is sufficient to assume uniqueness if you can assume that nobody is willing to spend $14 worth of computer time attacking you. Which is fine if there's no reason at all for anyone to attack you, but that's getting dangerously close to the amount of effort that might be worth it for some bored 14-year-old to do just for fun…

Comment: fair enough ... (I voted your answer up and imho its the correct one, the only reason I posted this as an answer is cause OP asked for it from my comments.) but really your answer sums it up best

Comment: My comment doesn't mean your answer is wrong; it just means the OP has to define his use case before _any_ answer is right… If attacks are not an issue (or they are, but MD5 provides enough protection), everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

i created a small duplicate file remover script few days back, which reads the content of the file and create a hash for it and then compare with the next file, in which even if the name is different the checksum is going to be the same..

```
import hashlib
import os

hash_table = {}
dups = []
path = "C:\\images"
for img in os.path.listdir(path):
    img_path = os.path.join(path, img)
    _file = open(img_path, "rb")
    content = _file.read()
    _file.close()
    md5 = hashlib.md5(content)
    _hash = md5.hexdigest()

    if _hash in hash_table.keys():
        dups.append(img)
    else:
        hash_table[_hash] = img
```

Comment: But is it certain that the files can't be different for same checksums?

Comment: no ... there is no way to guarantee sameness except checking byte by byte ... there is no shortcut ... this is very unlikely to collide but it still could ...

Comment: if the content of the file is same then logically they are duplicates, which means that they will create a same checksum.

Comment: do you understand how MD5 is generated ... look at rainbow tables for examples of things that have the same checksum but differ :P

Comment: @abhishekgarg I didnt ask for the method how to calculate, but as you have written it down. Just let me tell you its a very bad method to calculate the checksum especially if its a large file as you are reading it whole to the memory. Want to know a better way than post a question, I might answer the better method.

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra, please tell me the better way :), im always open to learn, i've just started.

Comment: @abhishekgarg: I've updated my answer to show how to hash a file without reading all of it into memory.